# update if exists or insert if does not exist in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I am working in WordPress and want to insert row only if it does not exist and if it exists from current user I want to update with the new value. Below code is fetching no results or null on ajax call and the console also does not show any errors. If I run the insert update query alonge they work but when used like this together they do not show any result. I have used ajax to simply pass the result to a div. So I am just pasting the php code here.

PHP Code

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_star', 'star' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_star', 'star');


    function star()
    {
        //variables

        $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
        $user=$user_info->user_login;
        $passedvalue = $_POST['clickval'];
        $competition = $_POST['compete'];
        $aid = $_POST['foo'];
        global $wpdb;    
        //$sqll = "SELECT zvotes.zvotes FROM zvotes WHERE zvotes.votedby = '$user' && zvotes.zcompetition = '$competition'";
        $previous = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT zvotes.zvotes FROM zvotes WHERE zvotes.votedby = '$user' && zvotes.zcompetition = '$competition'");

        if(count($previous)>0){

            $wpdb->update('zvotes', array('zvotes'=>$passedvalue), array('votedby'=>$user, 'competition'=>$competition));

            echo json_encode("there is a previous entry");die();}    

        $wpdb->insert(
            'zvotes',
            array(
                    'zvotes' => $passedvalue,
                    'zcompetition' => $competition,
                    'aid' => $aid,
                    'votedby' => $user
                ));

        echo json_encode("insert works");die();

    }
```

Comment: it is named UPSERT. Google to help

Comment: @splash58 ... do you think it can achieve what I want to like insert only if there is no row and if found update only. Can you please share a basic syntax because I am stuck and trying for two hours

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I have found this so how can I use this for my case because I am using two or three conditions in where clause $sql = "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}item_info (post_id,item_stock) VALUES (%d,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_stock = %s";
// var_dump($sql); // debug
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$post_id,$item_stock,$item_stock);
// var_dump($sql); // debug
$wpdb->query($sql);

Answer (score 2):

Use `$wpdb->replace('table_name',[ 'column' => 'value', 'column2'=> 12], ['%s','%d']);`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#REPLACE_row has a great breakdown

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try and update the table using `$wpdb->update`, I am using the id in the following code, but you can use any criteria.

```
$result = $wpdb->update($tableName, $info, array('id' => $info["id"]));
//If nothing found to update, it will try and create the record.
if ($result === FALSE || $result < 1) {
    $wpdb->insert($tableName, $info);
}
```

**Update() result output**

- `$result === FALSE` : Fail
- `$result === 0` : Success, but nothing updated
- `$result > 1`: Success and updated

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the syntax is `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.  You need a unique key on the columns used for defining the variables.  I am guessing it is this:

```
create unique index idx_zvotes_votedby_competition on zvotes(voted_by, zcompetition);
```

Then the code looks something like this:

```
insert into zvotes (voted_by, zcompetition, zvotes)
    select $voted_by, @zcompetition, $zvotes
on duplicate key update zvotes = zvotes + value(zvotes);
```

You are not clear on the data structure, so this is an approximation of what you probably need.

Comment: No this does not solve my problem ... can anybody suggest what I can do in this case .. thanks .. wordpress gurus here !